# Want to refer to the variable in ng-repeat in another div ng-if. AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have fetched docs from my database. now what I want to do is based on different doc.statuses, want to display different messages. How to go about it?

```
<p>
    <a target="_blank" style="margin-right:5px" ng-repeat="doc in homeCtrl.getDocs(docType.objectId)" href="{{doc.document.url}}">
        <div ng-if="doc.status == 'approved'">Hello</div>
        <span class="label label-success"><i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass"></i>{{doc.status}}</span>
       <br>{{doc.comment}}<br>
    </a>
</p>
```

so the ng-if in the div is not working. How to refer to the doc used in ng-repeat?

EDIT:
I still can't figure out. My controller looks like this(I'm using a Parse backend)

The controller looks like this

```
class HomeController {

  constructor($scope, $state, itemsService, $location, $ionicLoading) {
    'ngInject';
    const self = this;
    self.UserDocument = Parse.Object.extend('UserDocument');
    self.$scope = $scope;
    self.$scope.user = {};
    self.$scope.objUserDocument = {};
    self.$scope.userDocumentTypes = [];
    self.loading = $ionicLoading;
    // self.$scope.docs = [];

    $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function(event, data) {
      if (!Parse.User.current()) {
        $location.url('/signup');
      } else {
        // self.$scope.user = window.buddy;
        self._getDocumentTypes();
        // self.$scope.user.firstName = objUser.get('firstName');
        // self.$scope.user.lastName = objUser.get('lastName');
        // console.log(objUser.get('docs'));
      }

    });
    window.homeCtrl = this;
  }


  getDocs(id) {
    const self = this;
    if (self.$scope.user.docs && self.$scope.user.docs.length) {
      var docs = self.$scope.user.docs.filter(d => id == d.docType.objectId);
      return docs;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

}

export default HomeController;
```

````

Comment: You mean that in all other elements `doc` is visible (like in `{{doc.comment}}`) but not for `ng-if`?

Comment: yup! but if use the ng-if in <a> (where ng-repeat is referred) It is working

Comment: Can you make a plunker of your example?

Comment: I have added the related functions in the controller. Have a look. I am using a Parse backend. {{XYZ}} is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

ng-if works fine:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span>{{item.id}}</span>
  <span ng-if="item.status === 'approved'">approved</span>
  <span ng-if="item.status === 'rejected'">rejected</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {status: 'approved', id: 1},
    {status: 'approved', id: 2},
    {status: 'rejected', id: 3},
    {status: 'rejected', id: 4}
    ]
}])
```

Here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/wIX46rZHBNGHdv1S3LKg?p=preview

Comment: Yes, it works also with `<a>` as parent element: http://plnkr.co/edit/DauPBOkFKqsaYhvzrlZP?p=preview

Comment: Thanks..but not working at my end. I have added the controller if that can help

Comment: You can try to use `{{doc.status}}` in your ng-repeat to view the status field of each element

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the function that retrieves the docs inside you controller and pass the result to ng-repeat instead.

```
ng-repeat="doc in docs"
```

and

```
.controller('YourController', function($scope) {
    $scope.docs = getDocs(id);
});
```